# How to achieve partial rendering in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Below is the html code

```
<select name="userSelected" id="ddl">
    <option value="-1">---Select---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
        <option value="${user.userId}">${user.userName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="showForm(this)">view</button>
<div id="test">
    <form:form id="expenseView"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteExpense"
        method="POST" modelAttribute="users">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td align="justify"></td>
                    <td align="justify"><b>Item</b></td>
                    <td align="justify"><b>Amount</b></td>
                    <td align="justify"><b>ExpenseDate</b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <c:forEach items="${expenseList}" var="list" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"
                        value="${list.expenseId}"></td>
                    <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
                    <td>${list.amount}</td>
                    <td>${list.expenseDate}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form:form>
</div>
```

And this is the jquery, ajax am using

```
var hideResult = function() {
        $('#test').hide();
    };
    var showResult = function() {
        $('#test').show();
    };

    function showForm(myFormType) {

        var selectedValue = $('#ddl option:selected').val();

        var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewExpense" + "?Id="
                + selectedValue;

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
        }).success(function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        });
        showResult();
    }
```

what I want to achieve is when a user hits a view button the only the div section should be refreshed so for that I am using ajax, but as my controller is sending a view name so what its doing is that it is refreshing that part only but with that one more of same kind of dropdown gets added.
Maybe, because my controller is sending the whole view. So how to achieve partial rendering of view. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you can use.

You could adjust what is sent based on a parameter in the request or parse the response for the html that you want once it is received.

Here's how to do second approach

```
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
    }).success(function(data) {
        var $form = $(data).find('#expenseView');
        $('#test').html($form);
    });
```

You can also use replace the above with `load()` shorthand method of `$.ajax` to do this:

```
$('#test').load(url +' #expenseView');// note that space before selector is important
```